# How to avoid wget hanging

Tags: linux, debian, wget

I use a gsm modem to download image files sent to it via mms. From my debian box at home it works with no problem. However, whenever I try it from my deban box at my office I get:

```
wget -d -r --tries=2 --bind-address=25.234.65.247 http://ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?T=mavodi-1-13b-61-4-9c-6610710
Setting --recursive (recursive) to 1
Setting --tries (tries) to 2
Setting --bind-address (bindaddress) to 25.234.65.247
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.16 on linux-gnu.

URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Enqueuing http://ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?T=mavodi-1-13b-61-4-9c-6610710 at depth 0
Queue count 1, maxcount 1.
[IRI Enqueuing ‘http://ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?T=mavodi-1-13b-61-4-9c-6610710’ with ‘UTF-8’
Dequeuing http://ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?T=mavodi-1-13b-61-4-9c-6610710 at depth 0
Queue count 0, maxcount 1.
--2018-12-20 09:32:51--  http://ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc?T=mavodi-1-13b-61-4-9c-6610710
Resolving ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com (ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com)... 208.54.99.202
Caching ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com => 208.54.99.202
Connecting to ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com (ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com)|208.54.99.202|:80... Releasing 0x08c080b8 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x08c080b8.
Closed fd 4
failed: Connection timed out.
Releasing 0x08c07fc8 (new refcount 1).
Retrying.
```

It eventually gives up after how ever many tries I set with tries=n. Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Works for me (well, it connects and gets a 308...). Possibly a firewall somewhere? Can you ping the server?

Comment: Welcome cross posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873871/how-avoid-wget-hanging-on-connection

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for the reply. Yes, I can ping it.

ping -I ppp0 ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com
PING ttnmmsget.msg.eng.t-mobile.com (208.54.99.202) from 25.33.197.248 ppp0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mca6336d0.tmodns.net (208.54.99.202): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=929 ms
64 bytes from mca6336d0.tmodns.net (208.54.99.202): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=529 ms
64 bytes from mca6336d0.tmodns.net (208.54.99.202): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=528 ms

Comment: I think this might be my problem: nmap 25.234.85.66 -p 80

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-12-21 08:11 CST
Nmap scan report for 25.234.85.66
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp closed http

I take it I need to open port 80. Any idea how to do that?